# How can I find sum mean of 2d array with positive number and negative number in c

Tags: c, arrays

How can I find sum mean of 2d array with positive number and negative number in c

```
int data[4][5] = {
    {3,-6,1,-5,7},
    {-2,9,-3,5,4},
    {7,3,-4,0,-6},
    {9,-2,-5,8,3}
};

>Sum of all positive number 
>Mean of all positve number 
>Sum of all negative number
>Mean of all negative number
```

I'm freshman from university and I have final exam tomorrow please help me practice. Thanks!

Comment: Scan the whole array if(a[i][j] > 0), find their sum and keep track of total positive numbers. divide sum/total. Similarly do it for negative numbers.

Comment: Can you give me the code to explain me please sir.

Comment: @RoadRunner Thanks you I wil pratice more for it,But what wrong with LPs Did I do anything wrong in this post if wrong I will just delete it

Comment: Actually "LPs" thinks himself extra smart. -_-. One advice, don't ask for codes because stackoverflow is not for problem solving. Show the community what you have done, it will come up with edits and better solutions.

Comment: @Apy thanks you so much for advice , Im just newbie sorry for that

Comment: I know that. You just joined. Community members should encourage rather than showing off themselves. Here, take a look at LPs comments. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41158324/how-to-find-the-output-of-this-code

Comment: @Apy What a rude guy.

Comment: Leave it. All the best for your exams. :)

Comment: @Apy Thanks!, Do you mind if I ask for your facebook to contact you?

Comment: @Tony Here was my code before [Demo](http://ideone.com/DoXqzY), it was asked to get taken down. Good luck on your exam. I also just undeleted my answer, feel free to use it and learn from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that works on a 1D array. You can understand this, and apply it to your 2D problem.

We need variables to keep track of two sums (positive and negative numbers), these can be `int`s. We need two variables to count how many positive and negative numbers are in the array, and these can also be `int`s. Then we need two variables to store the means in. These could be `float`s, but it is better to just use `double`s for this type of calculation. Finally, we need a variable to index the array with. I usually use a `size_t` variable for this sort of thing, but here I will use another `int`.

After looping through the array to find sums and counts, it is time to calculate the means. One pitfall to watch out for here is that all of the arguments are of type `int`, so if we calculated:

```
mean_pos = sum_pos / count_pos;
```

we would be using integer division, and losing the fractional part of the result. We can multiply `count_pos * 1.0` to convert this value to a `double` and use floating point division.

I should point out that this code does not count zero values, which is what your problem specification suggested. If you want to count the zeros (which are neither positive or negative) in one of the means, it should be a simple matter for you to modify the code.

Good luck with your tests.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int data[10] = { 3, -6, 1, -5, 7, -2, 9, -3, 5, 4 };
    int sum_pos = 0;
    int sum_neg = 0;
    int count_pos = 0;
    int count_neg = 0;
    double mean_pos, mean_neg;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (data[i] > 0) {
            sum_pos += data[i];
            ++count_pos;
        } else if (data[i] < 0) {
            sum_neg += data[i];
            ++count_neg;
        }
    }

    mean_pos = sum_pos / (count_pos * 1.0);
    mean_neg = sum_neg / (count_neg * 1.0);

    printf("Sum of positive numbers: %d\n", sum_pos);
    printf("Mean of positive numbers: %f\n", mean_pos);
    printf("Sum of negative numbers: %d\n", sum_neg);
    printf("Mean of negative numbers: %f\n", mean_neg);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks you so much ! , I will learn from it,

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROWS 4
#define COLS 5

int
main(void) {
    int data[ROWS][COLS] = {{3,-6,1,-5,7},
                            {-2,9,-3,5,4},
                            {7,3,-4,0,-6},
                            {9,-2,-5,8,3}};
    int numpos = 0, numneg = 0;
    int possum = 0, negsum = 0;
    int row, col;

    for (row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
            if (data[row][col] > 0) {
                possum += data[row][col];
                numpos++;
            } else if (data[row][col] < 0) {
                negsum += data[row][col];
                numneg++;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Sum of all positive numbers = %d\n", possum);
    printf("Mean of all positive numbers = %.2f\n", ((1.0) * possum) / numpos);
    printf("Sum of all negative numbers = %d\n", negsum);
    printf("Mean of all negative numbers = %.2f\n", ((1.0) * negsum) / numneg);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not feed the animals....

Comment: Thanks you so much !.

Comment: I did it.... ;)